# Diagnostic connector broken; wires corroded and pulled out of the housing

Tags: ford, cel, part-identification, diagnostics, f-150

1990 f150, XLT Lariat. Has been having idling issues, and the check engine light flicked on. I went to try and pull codes off, and realized that the wires inside the diagnostic connector had corroded. I can't seem to find a replacement part, or a method to reconnect the wires. The housing itself is shattered on one side too, which is probably how moisture got in there in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, your best bet is to go to a wrecking yard where you can pull your own parts, find one in a Ford vehicle (F150 would probably work the best). Pull the data link connector (DLC) from the truck along with several inches (6" or more) from the wiring harness. Take it home and splice it into where your DLC is at now. This will allow you access back into your computer. The only reason why I suggest another Ford truck around the same age is the color indicators of the wires should be the same and should make it easier for you to match them up.

Comment: Cut and splice one wire at a time!  Don't want to mix anything up.